# How to fetch the #[app.name] , environment variable and #[exception.getMessage()] in Mule dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, dataweave

Actually what I am trying to do is whenever exception/error occurs in application it will come to catch exception strategy, here I'm trying to create a xml request which contains application name, timestamp and error details and calling one rest service with this xml as input. Could you please help me in doing this..?? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There nothing you can do access those expressions in dataweave, you might need to store those in flowVars then access the flowVars in dataweave like flowVars."name_of_var".

Regards,
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

You can find error handling block in your flow.
Inside that you can catch the exception with the MEL syntax.

```
#[Exception.causedBy(corresponding class)]
```

once if there is an exception based on some class then inside that you can define your strategy.
In general you can catch any exception by `#[Exception!=null]`
If there is any exception occurs automatically the control will be passed here.
In that you can setpayload  `#[app.name], #[server.dateTime],#[Exception.getMessage()]`
Then you can proceed as you want.

Thanks!